# Using Linq extension methods on a internal EntitySet with a foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to set my EntitySet objects in my EDMX to be internal. But I am having issues when I switch from public to internal. The LINQ queries work as expected when I directly access the DBContext and the object name. But when i use the extension method the foreign keys are not being found.

example:

while this will not return any results.

```
API.FindAll<AuthenticationAPI>(x => x.UserName == username)
           .SelectMany(x => x.AuthenticationAPIRolesType)
           .Select(x => x.RoleType).ToList();
```

This will return the expected results.

```
API.AuthenticationAPI.Where(x => x.UserName == username).SelectMany(x => x.AuthenticationAPIRolesType)
           .Select(x => x.RoleType).ToList();
```

Here is the extension method.

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(this DbContext context, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        where T : class
    {
        var _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        if (_dbSet == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
        if (predicate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }
```

I am using Entity Framework 6.

Here are the classes:

```
public partial class AuthenticationAPI
{
    public AuthenticationAPI()
    {
        this.AuthenticationAPIRolesType = new HashSet<AuthenticationAPIRolesType>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AuthenticationAPIRolesType> AuthenticationAPIRolesType { get; set; }
}


public partial class AuthenticationAPIRolesType
{
    public AuthenticationAPIRolesType()
    {
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FK_AuthenticationAPI { get; set; }
    public string RoleType { get; set; }

    public virtual AuthenticationAPI AuthenticationAPI { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your call to `FindAll` shouldn't even compile at the moment, given that you're passing in `true` for a parameter of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Did you mean `x => true`? If that wasn't right in your post, is there any other part of the code you posted which isn't the real code?

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated it to the actual code.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what's inside `API.AuthenticationAPI`.

Comment: Still doesn't tell what `API.AuthenticationAPI` is. A `DbSet`?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes it is a DbSet.